# How to take control of Dismissal of UIAlertView in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I need to know if I can decide in the action method of the Buttons of UIAlertView whether to dismiss the alertView or not. In short On click of certain buttons of AlertView, I dont want my alert view to dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that I know of to do this.  But it sounds like you're using UIAlertView in a manner for which it's not really intended.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I know about its intended manner, I wanted to have that functionality to validate the data of a textBox in my alert box. I was planning to use UIVIew but thought AlertView will be more suitable in my case. Anyways I can do this by using a custom button instead of using the buttons available from AlertView. But just wanted to know if there is a way out or not.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding my own custom button instead of using the ones provided by the AlertView. After assigning my own actions to this Buttons I was able to control the dismissal of the alertview from those actions.